# ZF2 Remember me

Tags: php, session, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, remember-me

I'm trying to remember the session when the user logs on successfully.

The time of the session works correctly, just does not work when I close the tab of my browser (Chrome) and back into the page.

```
if ($authResult->isValid()) {
                    $identity = $authResult->getIdentity();
                    $authService->getStorage()->write($identity);
                    $time = 8640000; // 100 days 8640000/3600 = 2400 hours => 2400/24 = 100 days
                    if ($data['rememberme']==1) {
                        $sessionConfig = new SessionConfig();
                        $sessionConfig->setOptions(array(
                            'use_cookies' => true,
                            'cookie_httponly' => true,
                            'gc_maxlifetime' =>$time,
                            'cookie_lifetime' => $time,
                        ));
                        $manager = new SessionManager($sessionConfig);
                    }
                    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('application');
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not remove the session Cookies, to carry out checks through a different browser, such as Firefox